# Relationship between Markov chains and i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains, markov-process

I am studying Markov chains.  I understand that a sequence of i.i.d. random variables is a special type of Markov chain.  However, I am trying to prove that a finite-valued Markov chain is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables if and only if all the rows of the transition matrix are the same.

For a general proof, it is not enough to just show that the statement holds for a matrix of dimensions, say 2 x 2 or 3 x 3, which is what I've been trying.

Is there anything I am missing in regards to how we can use the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations here?  Thanks a lot for any insight.

Comment: You should elaborate/clarify on what you are referring to as an "i.i.d. sequence". Can you add more definition?

Comment: @jameselmore looks fine to me, doesn’t need any more clarification

Comment: @jameselmore Thank you!  For sure, here I have a Markov chain given by a sequence of random variables: X0, X1, X2, ....  Each Xi takes values from a finite state space, which I take as S = { A, B }.  So I have Xi element of S.  Now, I am trying to prove that this markov chain given by X0, X1, X2, .... can be i.i.d. (independent and identically distributed) if and only if all the rows of the transition matrix are the same.

Comment: Can I use proof by contradiction?  As in, take an example transition matrix that does not have all its rows to be the same (say row 1 will be 0.2, 0.8 and row 2 will be 0.6, 0.4).  And then, show that any 2 random variables from the sequence, say, X1 and X2, are not independent when the rows of the transition matrix are not the same?  Does this logic make sense to prove this?  Thank you!